# What directory and file structure to use for Puppet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, puppet

The Puppet tutorials I have read so far haven't mentioned how to structure the puppet `.pp`.

Can anyone share some experiences of what works and scales well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, please see my comments at: [How can the little guys effectively learn and use Puppet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/395990/how-can-the-little-guys-effectively-learn-and-use-puppet/396000#396000)

I followed the examples and guidelines in [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849515387). But part of my initial frustration was a lack of a standard or "best-practice" way of doing things with Puppet when, as a sysadmin, I expect some direction there.

You can basically create your own structure. Whatever makes sense... But I'd follow one of the examples for consistency. I ended up restructuring several times in a month as things started to make more and more sense to me.

The rest will depend heavily on your server infrastructure. If you have a large number of systems on ONE location, your manifest/module directory structure will look different than running servers in 20 co-location facilities... so the logical arrangement may be function-based or location-based. It'll really need to be tailored to your particular setup.

Then, there's the approach of [decentralized PuppetMasters or distributing manifests by Git or rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/408261/pros-and-cons-of-a-decentralized-puppet-architecture)... The book I linked above covers some of the scalability issues.