# Puppet: differences between centralized and decentralized manifest distribution

Tags: puppet

There seem to be two different ways to distribute puppet manifests:

1. **Centralized**:

   This involves running a central puppet master server which is periodically queried by puppet agents for changes.
2. **Decentralized**:

   In this case there is no central puppet master server and manifests are distributed to the nodes some other way, for example via Git. Then a node runs `puppet apply` to apply the changes.

I would like to know what are the main differences between the two approaches and if any puppet feature depends on a particular approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pros and Cons of a Decentralized Puppet Architecture](http://serverfault.com/questions/408261/pros-and-cons-of-a-decentralized-puppet-architecture)

Comment: I don't know, that duplicate question/answer isn't that great either. A lot changed since then. Setting up a Puppetmaster is pretty easy for a professional. I wouldn't want to miss the advantage of centralized reporting (via Puppetdb). I think this question is pretty much opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

I use [Puppet Enterprise](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-enterprise), so out of the box, it's pretty well-equipped to handle the geographically-dispersed environment I manage. For me, I also leverage [mcollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective), which provides other benefits.

See what works for you. Everyone does this differently. I wouldn't use a Git approach unless you had a specific constraint. E.g. do it the *Puppet* way unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about others but stuff like exported resources definitely depend on having a puppet master with puppet DB.

I doubt there will be stuff that you can do with a decentralized architecture and not with a centralized one.

Comment: PuppetDB yes, but you can use that with `puppet apply` and no master just fine.